# Why am i only able to enchant items to 8% even though Enchanting is 100 and I have all perks

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Enchanter is 5/5, and everything says enchantments on armor are 25% stronger but when I try to Enchant anything it says 8%.

Answer (score 6):

If your Enchanting skill is maxed out with all the perks and the armor's enchantment is only 8%, it sounds like you are trying to enchant the armor with a low ranking soul gem (probably petty).

According to the [UESP Enchanting Effects guide](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Apparel), the following is the formula that calculates the percentage of the enchantment:

> net magnitude = base magnitude * soul multiplier * skill multiplier * (1 + Enchanter perk) * (1 + specific perk modifier)

The soul multiplier varies based on which soul gem being used. So if you are using a petty soul gem, you should expected the enchantments to be 1/12th of their effectiveness